# Given a point inside a rectangle, determine the side that's closest to the point

Tags: performance, algorithm, math

I was curious if there was an elegant way to do this, aside from just calculating the distance from the point to each side and finding the minimum.

Some things I've thought about:
If it's a square, we can just draw the diagonals and figure out which of the 4 regions the point falls on. Each of these region corresponds to a closest side.

Perhaps we can divide up the rectangle into squares and go somewhere from there?

It seems an alternative solution would be too complicated and not worth looking for.

Comment: You can also draw the diagonals for the rectangle and figure out which of the 4 regions the point belongs to.

Comment: @krjampani, it's wrong for rectangle. Each square does not determine set of closest points to each side.

Comment: Yes.. you are right that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rectangle you can use following regions:

[image: Rectangle closest points regions]

Comment: thanks :) i'm embarrassed i didn't see this!

Answer (score 0):

I think the rectangle is not orthogonal to the coordinate system. First calculate the middle point of every side. This should be simple depending on how you have define the rectangle.

Then calculate the distance to this middle points. The smallest distance is the nearest side. You need not to calculate the full distance with pytagoras. The sum of the squared is enough.