# How to determine the normal when ball hits rectangle?

Tags: android, collision

I have this constants defined, but I'm not sure how to find the normal index.

```
public static final int LEFT = 0;
public static final int RIGHT = 1;
public static final int UP = 2;
public static final int DOWN = 3;

public float[] normals = {-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1};

public float4 getNormal(int index)
{
    return new float4(normals[index * 2], normals[index * 2 + 1], 0);
}

public static int normal(float x, float y, RectF rect)
{
    // need to find the normal index here
    return normal_index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for inside and outside points (radius centers):

```
public static int normal_index(float x, float y, RectF rect)
{
    float cx = rect.left + rect.width() * 0.5f;
    float cy = rect.top + rect.height() * 0.5f;

    boolean a = x - rect.left < rect.bottom - y;
    boolean b = x - rect.left < y - rect.top;
    boolean c = x - rect.right < y - rect.bottom;
    boolean d = x - rect.right < rect.top - y;

    if (a && b && x < cx ) return LEFT;     
    else if (!c && !d && x >= cx ) return RIGHT;        
    else if (!a && c && y >= cy ) return DOWN;      
    else if (!b && d && y < cy ) return UP;

    return -1;
}
```

The question seems related to this question [Given a point inside a rectangle, determine the side that's closest to the point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867219/given-a-point-inside-a-rectangle-determine-the-side-thats-closest-to-the-point)

For the lines a, b, c, d, I've got similar picture:

[image: pic]